# How kubernetes podAffinity priority score is computed?

Tags: kubernetes, cluster-computing, kubernetes-pod

If I use a `preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution` rule within a `podAffinity`, is the score of each node computed based on *the number* of pods on that node that match my rule? That is, would a node that has two pods that match my rule be preferred to another node which has only one pod matching my rule?

The [`podAffinity`'s design proposal algorithm](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/scheduling/podaffinity.md#algorithm) suggests that it does not depend on the number of pods:
`Repeat Step 1a except replace the last line with "foreach node W of {N} having label [key=H.TopologyKey, value=any K such that M[K]>0], Y[W]++"`

Is there a way to make a `podAffinity` rule that DOES depend on the number of pods in each node matching my rule?

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes mechanism tries to run as many pods as possible on one node. It hasn't a mechanism to calculate the number of pods with the same labels, it relies on resources.